# Vertical order binary tree traversal

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am trying to do vertical order traversal on a binary tree like:

```
       1
     /   \
   2       3
 /  \    /   \
4    6   7    8
 \           / \
   5        9   10
```

First of all i am using a pre order traversal and then creating a hash map to store the horizontal distance of the nodes from the root.

Horizontal distance means that the left part from the root will be considered as -1,-2 and so on. Like a negative X axis, where root is origin and starts from 0
So node 2 will be given -1, 4 will be given -2.
However, 1,6,7 will be given 0 as they are not away from root node but lie in same position.
and towards right, distance will become positive so 3 will get distance 1, 8 will get 2 and so on.

I am expected to get distance : node relation as :
{0: [1,6,7] , -1 : [2,5] , -2 : 4 , 1:[3,9] , 2:8 , 3:10 }
but i get output like this:

```
Node : Distance
1 0
2 -1
4 -2
5 -1
6 1
3 3
7 2
8 4
9 3
10 5
```

My code is as follows:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def vertical_traversal(root):
    current = root
    stack = []
    hd = {}   // map
    k = 0

    while True:
        if current is not None:            
            stack.append(current)         
            hd.setdefault(k, [])
            hd[k].append(current.data)           
            current = current.left
            k += -1

        elif stack:
            k += 1
            current = stack.pop()       
            current = current.right

            if current:
                k += 1

        else:
            break
    return hd
```

I certainly think the problem is with the 'k' , but I do not know how to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

As seeing your code there is a problem in logic so please refer below updated code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
class St:
    def __init__(self, root,  v):
        self.root = root
        self.v = v

def vertical_traversal(root):
    current = root
    stack = []
    hd = {}
    k = 0

    while True:
        if current is not None:
            stack.append(St(current, k))
            hd.setdefault(k, [])
            hd[k].append(current.data)
            current = current.left
            k += -1

        elif stack:
            ct = stack.pop()
            current = ct.root
            current = current.right
            if(current != None):
                k  = ct.v+1

        else:
            break
    return hd

root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(6)
root.left.left.right = Node(5)
root.right.left = Node(7)
root.right.right = Node(8)
root.right.right.left = Node(9)
root.right.right.right = Node(10)
print ("Vertical order traversal is")
d = vertical_traversal(root)
print(d)
```

For more clarification please let me know